# Caret/CaretEnsemble: Wrong model Type for Regression

Tags: r, regression, data-science, r-caret

I am attempting to build an ensemble of machine learning algorithms, the first using boosting algorithms and the second using stacking algorithms. When I try to create my model, I get the following error:

```
Error: wrong model type for regression
```

Here is my Code:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)

#Remove Null Values
Data <- Data[complete.cases(Data), ]    

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, 
savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs=TRUE)
algorithmList <- c('lda', 'rpart', 'glm', 'knn', 'svmRadial')
set.seed(seed)
models <- caretList(Setup~Age+Balance+Dcny2Rcvd+PCA, 
data=data, trControl=control, methodList=algorithmList)
results <- resamples(models)
summary(results)
dotplot(results)
```

Here is an example of my data:

```
Number    Setup      R         D2R     A        B       PCA   
123        1        381        6618    25      2500      2
124        0        200        100     30      3500      1
125        0        100        62      18      4000      1
126        1        202        75      21      1000      5
127        0        95         60      22      387       4
```

Question: Why am I getting this error?

I also got the same error for the following:

```
fit.c50 <- train(Setup~A+B+D2R+PCA+R, data=Data, trControl=control)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do classification with `caret`, your outcome `Setup` should be a factor variable. Since it is a number, it thinks that you are trying to do regression with classification models.

Answer (score 1):

`lda` means linear discriminant analysis, according to the [available models page](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html) in the caret docs. [Discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) is meant for classification, not regression.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to run it without lda

Comment: Also `classProbs=TRUE` is probably not a good idea for regression.

Answer (score 1):

In `neuralnet` I got both errors "wrong model for regression" or "wrong model for classification" when specifying the formula input in `train()`.

It was running correctly when providing the `y =` (output) and `x =` (features) matrices/data subsets in `train()`, for example:

```
train(y = Data$Setup, x = Data[ ,c("A","B","D2R","PCA","R")], trControl=control)
```